# Including an action result in jsp

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have the following jsp pages

```
header
Body
footer
left navigation
and right navigation
```

I include header footer left and right navigation to my body page, and for this I am using

```
<s:include/> 

<s:include value="leftnav.jsp/>
    leftnav.jsp contains link
    messages
    friendshiprequest
    ..
    ..
```

I want to display message count and new friendship request count. My problem is that by including   messages and friendship request count value is not displayed. I am not able to call necessary action by . Is there any way to include a page with an action result instead of page only.

Comment: use `<s:action executeResult="true"/>`

Comment: However it is better to create json producing actions and access them with ajax (that way you can periodically update the page without needing to reload it... like facebook does).

Comment: It could be done not using json also. Just use ajax an return jsp to some div.